# How to prevent row from expanding when a column has href/click event on it in a Mat-Table?

Tags: angular

I have a Mat-Table with nested nested tables which can be accessed by expanding the mat-rows .

For some columns i have a HREF link / Button which opens a popup / alert box . In that case i dont want the row to be expanded . Currently after the alert is closed the row gets expanded .

I tried researching online and tried with putting `href="javascript:void(0);"` in the anchor tag but that didnt work .

Here's the [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table-triplenested-mwytxr?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.html) for my issue

Can anyone help me with the suggestions ? Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your template, pass the `$event` to your `openAlert()` method.

```
(click)="openAlert($event)"
```

Then, in your typescript file update the `openAlert()` method to accept that event, and stop the propagation of the click event:

```
  openAlert(event: MouseEvent) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert("Hiiii");
  }
```

You can read more about stopPropagation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

Here's an [updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table-triplenested-1hmgvk).